# Get a different numbers of images from collectionCell with use firebase

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

How can i get a different numbers of images from **collectionCell** into **scrollView** with use **firebase**?
In my project i have **three viewController's**.

**FirstVC** - **collectionView** inside a **tableView**. **CollectionView** need for display the main images for scroll their. **TableView** need for display the name and and to scroll the table. (i.e. for those images which are in **FirstVC** in **collectionCell**).

**SecondVC** - only **collectionView**. Need for display the albums.

**ThirdVC** - only **scrollView** inside **viewController**. **ScrollView** need for a scroll images which are located in the **images** folder in **firebase**.

So when i click on **album** in **secondVC** on **collectionCell** i would like to see in **thirdVC** in **scrollView** images which are located in folder **images** in **firebase** for scrolling their.
My **firebase** struct is here:

```
{ 
  "users" : {
    "Y7EHcJuqQWZrVI1HBmNgccbPhm55" : {
      "name" : "Photos",
      "posts" : {
        "images" : {
          "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13",
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13"
        },
        "qwerty" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13"
      },
      "posts2" : {
        "images" : {
          "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13",
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13"
        },
        "qwerty" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city2.jpg?alt=media&token=64509e18-9884-4449-a081-c67393a7d82a"
      },
      "posts3" : {
        "images" : {
          "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13",
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13"
        },
        "qwerty" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/oko1.jpg?alt=media&token=fedea2cb-93b1-496c-9392-0b95f4ada7b5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my project in **googleDrive**, because I was faced with the problem of loading the project on **github**. My project is very simple, but I can't solve the problem about which wrote above.

[projectTestGoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fDEgf2udPjdktYeVdwUnJ1dW8/view?usp=sharing)

My **project code**:

**FirstVC**:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SDWebImage

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var nameArray = [String]()
    var addressArray = [String]()
    var postImage = [String](), postImage2 = [String](), postImage3 = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        loadName()
        loadImages()

        tableView.allowsSelection = true

    }
    func loadName() {        

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users"). 
        observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

            let value = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary
            self.nameArray.append(value["name"] as? String ?? "")
        })
    }
    func loadImages() {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").    
        observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

            let values = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary
            let posts = values["posts"] as? NSDictionary //[String: AnyObject]
            let posts2 = values["posts2"] as? NSDictionary //[String: AnyObject]
            let posts3 = values["posts3"] as? NSDictionary //[String: AnyObject]

            self.postImage.append(posts?["qwerty"] as? String ?? "")
            self.postImage2.append(posts2?["qwerty"] as? String ?? "")
            self.postImage3.append(posts3?["qwerty"] as? String ?? "")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue2" {
            if let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let indexPath = indexPaths as NSIndexPath
                let dvc = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
                let imagesArray = [self.postImage[indexPath.row],
                                   self.postImage2[indexPath.row],
                                   self.postImage3[indexPath.row]]
                dvc.images = imagesArray.filter({ !($0.isEmpty) })
            }
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return nameArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.userNameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]

        let array = [postImage[indexPath.row],
                     postImage2[indexPath.row],
                     postImage3[indexPath.row]]
        cell.postImageArray = array.filter({ !($0.isEmpty) })
        return cell
    }
}
```

**SecondVC**:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var images = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue3" {
            if let indexPaths = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
                let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
                let dvc = segue.destination as! ViewControllerScrollView
                dvc.images = [images[indexPath.item]]
            }
        }
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return images.count
    } 
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2

        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.item]))
        return cell
    }
}
```

**ThirdVC**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerScrollView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var images = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0..<images.count {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[i]))
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)

            scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, please show some code

Comment: added code in question

Comment: Ok, so currently your first and second VCs are working fine? you only want to display the images on the third VC?

Comment: do you want to show post title as a section and images into collection?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 , yes, first and second VCs are working fine. No, I want to see pictures that are on the branch **images** from firebase. If i click on posts2 (on secondVC) i would like to see **image** and **image2**, if i click on posts3 (on secondVC) i would like to see **image**, **image1** and **image2** from firebase on branch images.

Comment: Ok good, can you tell currently when you click on the image in VC2 using above code and what is happening? does some image show on  the VC3?

Comment: @3stud1ant3  i see only one image in **VC3**, this one image is key **qwerty** on branch **posts**, **posts2**, **posts3** depending on where I clicked.

Comment: Ok , can you please show the format of images array of SecondVC?

Comment: @3stud1ant3  not quite understand you, but I guess this is what you need, format is **.jpg**

Comment: is your problem solved or not?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 not solved

Comment: Ok , please add print(images) in viewDidLoad of VC3 and please show the output what is printed?

Comment: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city2.jpg?alt=media&token=64509e18-9884-4449-a081-c67393a7d82a"]
it's key **qwerty** of **posts2** from **firebase**. I think need get an **image** and **image2** and put thier in array and pass their to **thirdVC**, but i don't understand how to do it or am I mistaken.

Comment: You clicked an image from posts2 and this message showed? this array contains only one image?

Comment: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city2.jpg?alt=media&token=64509e18-9884-4449-a081-c67393a7d82a"]
Yes, only one image, but i don't understand how to show **image** and **image1**.
Me need to get branch **images** from **posts2** and show in **thirdVC** if i click on **image** from **post2**.

Comment: Ok, now in vc2 , you need to implement didSelectItem method, this is a uicollectionview delegate method, please when you implement this method,  and inside simply add this statement print([images[indexPath.item]]) and tell me the output

Comment: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city2.jpg?alt=media&token=64509e18-9884-4449-a081-c67393a7d82a"] it's on **secondVC**
["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city2.jpg?alt=media&token=64509e18-9884-4449-a081-c67393a7d82a"] it's from **thirdVC**

Comment: I think you can make a posts array like this if let posts1 = posts as? [String: Any] {
                        for (_, value) in posts1["images"] as! [String: Any] {
                                self.postImage.append(value as! String)
                        }
                }
                print("self.postImage \(self.postImage)") , repeat the same process for other arrays , use this in loadImages function in VC1

Comment: i delete this code **self.postImage.append(posts?["qwerty"] as? String ?? "")** or not need to delete this code?
And i get from **print(self.postImage)** this ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13"]

Comment: and if i haven't deleted i get from **print(self.postImage)** this
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/gallery%2F06BAB847-7C94-40A6-A9C8-C3A11B3F9C81.png?alt=media&token=4f797093-fbc7-437b-935c-d13be1409d13", 
 "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city2.jpg?alt=media&token=64509e18-9884-4449-a081-c67393a7d82a", 
 "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/oko1.jpg?alt=media&token=fedea2cb-93b1-496c-9392-0b95f4ada7b5
total three images against two images in post above

Comment: you need to delete that statement for qwerty and then you will have images for corresponding posts

Comment: I deleted it. And i got two images from branch **images** in **posts** - 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city2.jpg?alt=media&token=64509e18-9884-4449-a081-c67393a7d82a", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/oko1.jpg?alt=media&token=fedea2cb-93b1-496c-9392-0b95f4ada7b5"
So how i can use this to display on **thirdVC**?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 and i don't understand what do you mean about **print("self.postImage (self.postImage)")** it is the just simple string. i used just  **print(self.postImage)**

Comment: @3stud1ant3  can't help me?